# GitHub Webhook: Credentials not caching for www-data

Tags: php, bash, git, caching, credentials

I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-cache-github-credentials-for-pushing-commits) for properly setting up credentials caching.

All working smoothly, until I felt the need of setting up a **GitHub Webhook**.

So  I have placed a script under `/bash_scripts/..` folder which is correctly assigned to `www-data` recursively.

`ls -l` output:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 www-data root  4096 May  7 01:31 bash_scripts
```

And this is the content of one of the `bash` scripts for performing **pull**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/beta && git pull origin master
```

Then, I have a **PHP** endpoint calling shell_execute on the above script:

```
PHP> shell_exec('/bash_scripts/beta-github-hook.sh');
```

And I've been banging my head for an hours or so trying to find out why it wasn't being executed. The reason?

**Credentials** for **GitHub Repository** access are **not stored** for the user `www-data`. This is the command I've used to replicate the `shell_exec` on the terminal in order to get the output to the issue:

```
root@vps806928:/# su --shell /bash_scripts/beta-github-hook.sh www-data
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

On the other hand, if I execute the script as `root`, git uses the stored credentials:

```
root@vps806928:/# /bash_scripts/beta-github-hook.sh
From https://github.com/redacted
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
root@vps806928:/#
```

How can I make Git store credentials for `www-data`?

**EDIT**

The only workaround I found was editing the bash script and explicitly writing down the password for the repository to pull from:

```
git pull https://user:passwd@github.com/user/repo.git master
```

Although this is a workaround I'm still seeking for an answer to issue in question.

Comment: You set read permission for groups on `~/.ssh` and `sudo adduser {username} www-data` (or apache/httpd based on os)

Comment: @Viney what I've understood from your comment is that the best practice says that I should add `www-data` to an user group, instead of assigning the directory to `www-data`? Basically what I did was `chown -R www-data /direcotry`